# Using grep to find a string that starts with a character with numbers after

Tags: grep

Okay I have a file that contains numbers like this:

```
L21479
```

What I am trying to do is use grep (or a similar tool) to find all the strings in a file that have the format:

```
L#####
```

The # will be the number. SO an L followed by 5 numbers.

Is this even possible in grep? Should I load the file and perform regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `grep`, for example with the following command:

```
grep -E -o 'L[0-9]{5}'     name_of_file
```

For example, given a file with the text:

```
kasdhflkashl143112343214L232134614
3L1431413543454L2342L3523269ufoidu
gl9983ugsdu8768IUHI/(JHKJASHD/(888
```

The command above will output:

```
L23213
L14314
L35232
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just in a single file, you can do something along the lines of:

```
grep -e 'L[0-9]{5}' filename
```

If you need to search all files in a directory for these strings:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -e 'L[0-9]{5}'
```

Comment: nope, you need the `-o` flag or else grep will output whole lines which is a problem if match is found several times on same line.

Comment: That depends on what your are trying to find, just the string, or the line and the context it is in. If he was looking for line number he could add -n as well, but he didn't say what his application is for.

Comment: The { } characters don't have a special meaning in basic regular expressions. Either you have to write 'L[0-9]\{5\}' or switch to extended regular expressions with the `-E` switch.